# Aviary and Codeigniter saving blank file

Tags: php, codeigniter, aviary

So I am using Aviary to edit my pictures and I have this script that runs the application.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var featherEditor = new Aviary.Feather({
    apiKey: '',
    apiVersion: 3,
    theme: 'light', // Check out our new 'light' and 'dark' themes!
    tools: 'all',
    appendTo: '',
    onSave: function (imageID, newURL) {

    },
    postUrl: 'http://beta.usd309bands.org/upload/saveEditiedImage/',
    onError: function (errorObj) {
        alert(errorObj.message);
    }
});

function launchEditor(id, src) {
    featherEditor.launch({
        image: id,
        url: src
    });
    return false;
}
</script>
```

And then my php code for replacing the existing image with the edited image is as follows:

```
$image_data = file_get_contents($_REQUEST['url']);

file_put_contents("static/images/gallery/image1.jpg",$image_data);
```

This script makes contact with the existing file and overwrites it. But it overwrites it to be nothing. Just an empty `image1.jpg` file.

What am I doing wrong here? What more do I need to do in the php file?

Comment: Try echoing the `$image_data`. What do you get ?

Comment: I never actually see the page the php is processed on. It does it sorta like `ajax` So even when I echo out `$image_data` I can't see anything.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so everything I have in the php file is perfectly right and working. It was beyond my own coding where the issue was happening.

The server has two php configurations that must be met to handle this operation.

```
allow_url_fopen MUST BE EQUAL TO 1
allow_url_fopen='1';  // My Values
```

and

```
post_max_size MUST BE GREATER THAN THE IMAGE YOU ARE SAVING 
post_max_size ='120M'; // My Values
```